# Cannot find source file: /home/tensorflow/core/util/stats_calculator.cc

Tags: c++, tensorflow, cmake, ros, tensorflow-lite

I'm new to CMake and ROS.

I've been following the tutorial on setting up [tensorflow on ubuntu 20.0.4 (server) and rpi4](https://qengineering.eu/install-ubuntu-20.04-on-raspberry-pi-4.html), as well as [building tensorflow lite with CMake](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake) for my turtlebot3 project.

I added the following code to my CMakeLists.txt and modified my tensorflow source directory from **"${TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR}/tensorflow/lite"** to **"${TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR}/ubuntu/tensorflow/tensorflow/lite"**

```
set(TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR "" CACHE PATH
  "Directory that contains the TensorFlow project" )
if(NOT TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR)
  get_filename_component(TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../../../" ABSOLUTE)
endif()

add_subdirectory(
  "${TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR}/ubuntu/tensorflow/tensorflow/lite"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tensorflow-lite" EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

add_executable(MobileNetV1 src/scripts/MobileNetV1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MobileNetV1  ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} tensorflow-lite)
```

After building I experience the error below.

```
CMake Error at /home/ubuntu/tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/CMakeLists.txt:449 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    /home/tensorflow/core/util/stats_calculator.cc

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at /home/ubuntu/tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/CMakeLists.txt:449 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: benchmark_model
```

The files exist under **/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/util/stats_calculator.cc**. I don't know why its not being detected.

I don't know what to do next can some help me and explain why its giving me this error please.

Code example that I want to compile and run come from this [github](https://github.com/Qengineering/TensorFlow_Lite_SSD_RPi_64-bits) if you want to replicate.

And if you have links on easy to follow tutorials on how to setup tensorflow-lite on c++ that would be awesome!

Comment: Usually, good desiqned libs (meaning with CMake) just require a `add_subdirectory` pointing to their folder and a `target_link_libraries` depending how well it's designed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in your code, directory `TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR` **contains the TensorFlow project**. In other words, content of this directory should look like that: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow. And path to the tensorflow-lite should be exactly as written in the tutorial:

```
${TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR}/tensorflow/lite
```

If expression `"${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../../../"` doesn't denote root of TensorFlow project on your machine, then modify that **expression** but remain meaning of `TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR` variable.

You may print value of variable `TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR` after your computations and check that it actually refers to the root of Tensorflow project on your machine.

---

Actually, the variable `TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR` is **used** in the **TensorFlow project** itself. And exactly that usage causes problems when your setting of `TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR` doesn't corresponds to expectations of its meaning in Tensorflow project.

I wonder why the tutorial suggests to set `TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR` variable but does not note about the variable's usage in the TensorFlow project.

Instead of `TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR` variable your code could use any other variable which isn't used by Tensorflow. You could even **hardcode** the path to TensorFlow lite in your code:

```
# Do not define and do not use `TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR` variable at all
add_subdirectory(
  "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/tensorflow/lite"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tensorflow-lite" EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
```

When find variable `TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR` being not set, the script `tensorflow/lite/CMakeLists.txt` will correctly set it automatically: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/CMakeLists.txt#L42

Comment: So I tried your suggestion and I got the following warnings ```warning: passing argument 1 of ‘vld1q_dup_f16’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]``` and errors ```error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘vreinterpretq_s16_f32’```

Comment: I also printed the TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR before trying out your suggestion and it prints as ```/home```. How can I modify this so that TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR gives out the right directory

Comment: If you don't use `TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR` variable, then why do you ever bother about its value? The error message doesn't seem to connect with that variable.

Comment: I printed out the value to see what directory is being seen, but this was done before I followed your suggestion.

Comment: I finally got it working by hardcoding the tensorflow directory as per your suggestions. The error above was an incompatibility issue between tensorflow 2.4.1 and various packages in the package build directory. Upgrading to Tensorflow 2.5.0 resolved the issue. Thanks for the help and the explanation!